# survey paper on the construction of hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Is there a good survey paper which discusses the common ways of building hyperbolic $n$-manifolds?

Comment: Section 3.1 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/klein.pdf).

Comment: See Dave Witte-Morris' book for arithmetic groups, and section 6.5 for the non-arithmetic Gromov-Piatetskii-Shapiro examples. http://deductivepress.ca/  These and variants (together with Selberg's Lemma) are essentially the only known general method for proving the existence of finite volume hyperbolic $n$-manifolds (variants are given here https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04619). In 3 dimensions, in some sense the geometrization theorem gives a construction of all finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds. The Deligne-Mostow construction gives some examples as moduli spaces of polygons.

Comment: For recent constructions of finite volume hyperbolic manifolds with various properties, see: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2646
https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02747
https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10561
https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06536
https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12720

Answer (score 5):

Not a paper, but a book : [Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387331973) by John Ratcliffe. Chapters 10 and 11 might contain what you're looking for. Also available [here](http://entsphere.com/pub/pdf/Ratcliffe%20-%20Foundations%20of%20hyperbolic%20manifolds%20(2e)%20-%20GTM%20149.pdf).

Concerning 4-manifolds, you have a survey by Bruno Martelli [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03661.pdf).

Also, I'm sure you can find what you want typing construction of hyperbolic manifolds on your favorite search engine.